# HTTP timeout when making long running HTTP request from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

I am currently writing an Azure Function application to generate large PDF’s from HTML. I have an Azure Service Bus queue that gets pushed to via a website and then the queue messages get processed by the Azure Function (Basic Tier App Service Plan)

To generate the PDF’s, I make a HTTP request to an Azure Cloud Service from within the Azure function which generates me a byte array for which I write to Azure Blob Storage.

Sometimes the HTTP request can take up to 30 minutes. When I make any HTTP request at the moment that is longer than 4 minutes 30 seconds, I never get a response back. If my assumptions are correct, it’s due to the connection between the Cloud Service and the Azure Function timing out.

Has anyone got any suggestions which would allow for longer running HTTP requests using this infrastructure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely hitting the idle timeout on the cloud service side.  To fix this, set the idleTimeoutInMinutes on the InputEndpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configuration-and-management-faq#how-do-i-set-the-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer):

```
<Endpoints>
   <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="tcp" port="10100" idleTimeoutInMinutes="30" />
</Endpoints>
```

However this is probably the wrong solution.  You should not design a system that requires a response from an active HTTP connection for 30 minutes.  There are too many variables that can cause the connection to fail.  You should use an async model where you call the cloud service to start the job which will return a jobid, then periodically call the cloud service to check the status of the job.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply for a design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this kwill. After this, I went and reconsidered the approach and decided to try and use an Azure web job as you recommended. The reason we were running initially over HTTP was due to using a third party library which we couldn't run asynchronously. After converting to web job, we were able to get rid of the network request, the only issue we are having now is that when we generate the PDF, custom fonts do not load. I am going to try and embed these as base64 files instead, so we know we aren't running into resource blocks in Azure.